# I dont understand the logic behind working of media queries of foundation

Tags: css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I have past experience of working with foundation. So I started using foundation media queries rules for  creating responsive site.

```
// Small screens
@media only screen { } /* Define mobile styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { } /* max-width 640px, mobile-only styles, use when QAing mobile issues */

// Medium screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) { } /* min-width 641px, medium screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) { } /* min-width 641px and max-width 1024px, use when QAing tablet-only issues */

// Large screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) { } /* min-width 1025px, large screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) and (max-width: 90em) { } /* min-width 1025px and max-width 1440px, use when QAing large screen-only issues */

// XLarge screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) { } /* min-width 1441px, xlarge screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) and (max-width: 120em) { } /* min-width 1441px and max-width 1920px, use when QAing xlarge screen-only issues */

// XXLarge screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 120.063em) { } /* min-width 1921px, xxlarge screens */
```

Here is my problem:
I am trying to hide a menubar in mobiles that is shown in desktop version (like how show-for-small in foundation). So I have defined stylings for mobile inside the media query @media only screen and (max-width: 40em). Surprisingly it is not working . So I have added the following rule before the above mentioned rule, @media only screen { }, then it worked.

I also tried the combination of @media only screen and (min-width:5 em) and (max-width: 40em). It also did not work.

I also have viewport meta tag defined in my page. Can anyone explain me why this is happening so ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem maybe related to css specificity ( one command has higher priority)
so what about trying to put 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 40em)
in the last of your commands 
and also inspect element in browser to know if this command is overwrited by other command 
this is the most things happen with me when works with bootstrap ,wish this help you

Comment: Thank you Mohamed!!. It actually worked when I put the @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) at the last. Can you explain me what do you mean by "specificity" and how it takes priorities ?

Comment: Specificity determines, which CSS rule is applied by the browsers and it is usually the reason why your CSS-rules don’t apply to some elements . the command comes last has some  priority but not in all cases .this topic is explain this in more details you can check it
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
@SharanAinapurapu

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your element the hide-for-small class so that it won't show up on mobile screens: [Know as visibility classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html)